# Webpack module build failing when there are url's in the sass file

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I'm having trouble with the module build for my style.scss file. It seems that the image URLs that I've referenced are causing the build to fail and I'm not sure why. I thought it may be due to lacking an appropriate loader, so I installed the resolve-url-loader, which hasn't made any difference. I've looked at many other instances where people have experienced something similar and none of their solutions have worked for me.

**The Error:**

```
ERROR in ./src/sass/style.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../public/fonts/montserrat-v15-latin-600.eot' in 'C:\Users\Kaleshe\Local Sites\soundtruism\app\public\wp-content\themes\soundtruism\src\sass'
    at C:\Users\Kaleshe\Local S
```

**File Structure:**

[image: File structure]

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    frontend: ['./src/index.js', './src/sass/style.scss'],
    customizer: './src/customizer.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name]-bundle.js'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-sass-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
        options: {
          extract: true,
          spriteFilename: 'svg-defs.svg'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)\$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              outputPath: 'images/',
              name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
          },
          'img-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css'
    }),
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      open: 'external',
      host: 'soundtruism.local',
      files: '**/*.php',
      proxy: 'soundtruism.local',
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin(), new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin()]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

[PATH FROM THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkLvB.png)
You are referencing the fonts folder located in `public` directory. Where as the, the `sass` file is in `src/sass`. You need to use `../../public` to access the `public` directory.

The first `../` will take you to `src` and the next `../` will take you to `/`.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I'm so stupid haha. That made me able to figure out most of the issues I was having. I guess I was confused with where everything gets referenced. You've made my day! Thanks very much